# Inspector de elementos de Chrome no me muestra los medias Queries

Tags: google-chrome, mediaqueries

Tengo el problema que dije en el titulo, solo me carga el primer *Media Query*, pero los otros no los reconoce. No sé si toqué algo sin querer, porque la semana pasada me andaba ._..

Les muestro lo que pasa:

[image: Media query en Google]

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  header {
    background: rgb(36, 181, 200);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header {
    background: rgb(68, 49, 153);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  header {
    background: rgb(126, 26, 26);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Leonidas Esteban</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: Pronto, ya lo cambie!

Comment: Imagino que los media queries deben estar dentro de `estilos.css` no?? o lo tienes tal y como lo subiste

Comment: Acabo de probar tu css y me funciona bien, el problema debe ir por otro lado. ¿Cómo tienes instanciado tu `<header></header>`?

Comment: Prueba poniendo *background* a otro contenedor, al `body` por ejemplo en lugar del `header` para ver si funciona.

Comment: El codigo se ve sin problemas, a lo mejor el problema radica en tu codigo HTML, en la parte del header que fue la que no compartiste.

Comment: @israel-ICM ¿A que te referis con como tener instanciado el header? Ese codigo css no es el original, lo puse para que sea mas visible el error, sea cual sea el codigo con media query sigue pasando lo mismo igual, en el navegador me aparece eso, osea no me afecta pero me gustaria saber por que esta pasando eso de que solo aparece un media query, ya probe con otro codigo para ver si era problema del navegador pero no... anda bien ._.

Comment: Creo que es como decis @AlexGarzón, el problema debe estar en html

Comment: @Gedo97 me refiero a la parte del html donde esta el tag *header* para poder ver si hay algo por allí que ocasione el problema ya que los media queries que tienes funcionan bien, posiblemente pueda ser el path de tu archivo estilos.css pero según veo es necesario ver un poco mas de tu código.

Comment: Perdon que no te conteste antes Israel, pero ahora me empezo a  pasar algo raro, no me anda ningun media query de ningun codigo, probe con 3 proyectos diferentes, también abrir paginas diferentes y nada sigue pasando lo mismo. Deduzco que el problema es de google chrome... Pero los desinstale, lo instale denuevo, fui a settings de google y resetie todo, tambien en la consola hice reset  pero nada... la barra sigue tomando solo el primer media query, ya no se que hacer